# Saving dojo layout

Tags: javascript, dojo

In Dojo, I can dynamically generate layout by adding layout containers and adding children to them:

```
var bc = new BorderContainer({
    style: "height: 300px; width: 500px;"
});

// create a ContentPane as the left pane in the BorderContainer
var cp1 = new ContentPane({
    region: "left",
    style: "width: 100px",
    content: "hello world"
});
bc.addChild(cp1);
```

Our application allows the user to add tabs, or new content panes dynamically, and I'd like to save off this new layout.  I can't seem to find an easy way in Dojo to accomplish this.

Is there a way in Dojo to get an object representation for a dynamically generated layout without me having to scrape the DOM looking for dijit/layout in the data-dojo-type attributes?

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/..."
```

I need something similar to GoldenLayout where I can get and object representation of the current layout (GoldenLayout returns a JSON object hierarchically detailing the layout).

Unfortunately, I am stuck with Dojo and cannot move to GoldenLayout.

I do not need a JSON object necessarily, as I could convert to one. What I do need, is an object that has the current layout with all the content panes and tabs so that I can save it and later load it the next time a user logs in.

Currently using Dodo 1.12

Comment: Hm maybe you can save the Layout in a cookie and read it out next time the user starts the Projekt...

Comment: My issue isn't about saving or retrieving the layout (I'll be sending to the server). This issue is that Dojo, as far as I can tell, does not have an easy way to get me the layout in a compact savable form. Not without me scraping the DOM and creating my own format.  Dojo has to have some sort of internal format...if only I can get it.